# Android translate app name

Tags: android

I'd like to know if it is possible to translate the actual name of the app that people will search for in the Google Play Store? For example, if the name of my app is "Hello", the same app should be found if one person searches for "Hello" and another one searches for "Hola".

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can!

In the Google Play Developer Console you can see all languages for your app.
You just have to set a different title for each language in the "Store Listing" tab.